# iPhone app has compile error with linker error about IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1 but it seems to be already set to that

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I just got the latest version of the code and I had this compile error:

```
Ld /Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnlineMarketing-adupuelybnhjiuehwdqsligdkure/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OnlineMarketing.app/OnlineMarketing normal i386
    cd /Users/alexgenadinik/Desktop/Onlinemarketing
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnlineMarketing-adupuelybnhjiuehwdqsligdkure/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnlineMarketing-adupuelybnhjiuehwdqsligdkure/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnlineMarketing-adupuelybnhjiuehwdqsligdkure/Build/Intermediates/OnlineMarketing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OnlineMarketing.build/Objects-normal/i386/OnlineMarketing.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods-OnlineMarketing -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnlineMarketing-adupuelybnhjiuehwdqsligdkure/Build/Intermediates/OnlineMarketing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OnlineMarketing.build/Objects-normal/i386/OnlineMarketing_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnlineMarketing-adupuelybnhjiuehwdqsligdkure/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OnlineMarketing.app/OnlineMarketing
```

But in my build settings, this is set:

[image]

Would anyone know how to fix this and why it is happening?

Here is the screenshot with the error:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any error in the snippet you posted.  Can you post a screenshot of the error list?  (The tirangle exclamation point, then click on the error and it will bring up the compile report with error)

Comment: @Putz1103 thank you - I just added the screenshot with the error. It says: ld: library not found for -lPods-OnlineMarketing
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Your yellow highlight box is covering exactly what I wanted to see...  Can't see still, danget...

Comment: I just posted the stuff that is blocked by it in my previous message :)

Comment: Nevermind...  I didn't read your full comment.

Comment: That error is telling me that your project is not building with the library dependancy intact.  Go to your project build phases (click on project name, then go to build phases) and make sure that the "Target dependancies" and "Link binary with libraries" contain your `lPods-OnlineMarketing` library.

Comment: @Putz1103 there is actually nothing listed under the target dependencies.

Comment: Oh wait sorry....when I clicked the "Link binary with libraries" I do see 4 items and the missing one in red! How do I get it to not be in red? :)

Comment: Find out how to build that missing library and make it no longer in red (not found) and you should be good to go.  Good luck with that.

Comment: .. or clean your derivedData and restart Xcode :)

Comment: @TonyMkenu how do I actually clean my derived data? :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that there is a missing dependancy.  Somewhere you are trying to use (what looks like a custom) library that the compiler doesn't know where to find.  Fix that broken link (the library trying to be linked to) and you should be good to go.  But since it's a custom built library there's not much there that I can help with.  The only advice I have is that if the library is in the project and needs to be rebuilt on compile then it should be listed in the "Target Dependencies" section of "Build Phases" as well as in "Link Binaries WithLibraries" section.